# Drupal: what's the Drupal id for the "Save Button"?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

what's the hook for the Save Button in Drupal ?

I've tried

```
  $form['submit']['#weight']  = -50;
```

But it doesn't work.
I'm sure the template.php file works because for example:

```
  $form['author']['#weight']  = -50;
```

works.

Thanks

Comment: I've actually tried $form['submit']['#value'] = 'Hello'; and the word "Hello" is added to my node (but not as label replacement, just before the Save button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node form is built by [node_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_form).
All of the buttons at the bottom of the form are contained in `$form['buttons']`, so the information for the submit button is `$form['buttons']['submit']`